# dPlots gives empty tooltip-box

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts, dimple.js

I tried to dispaly in a shiny app some examples of demo(topic = "dimple",package = "rCharts").
But the tooltip boxes are empty when I wrap it in a shiny app.
This is my minimal example:

```
require(shiny)
require(rCharts)

df <- data.frame(user=LETTERS[1:3],amount=rnorm(3))

ui <- fluidPage(
    helpText("Clicking on graph gives empty frame instead of values,\n",
             "while the dotted line to the y-axis is paint well."),
    chartOutput("myPlot","dimple"))

server <- function(input,output){

  output$myPlot <- renderChart2({
    dd <<- dPlot(x = "user",y = "amount",data = df,type="bar")
    return(dd)
  })

}
runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

I see a similiarity to question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693805/rcharts-dimple-tooltip-box-empty-in-shiny-app], but I wasn't able to follows the workaround. And maybe after 3 years there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same problem, it was fixed in version 2 of dimple so make sure you are using the latest release.  Alternatively the workaround just required you to add some css:

```
.tooltip {
    opacity: 1 !Important;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I used rCharts_0.4.5 which comes with dimple.v.1.1.4. Because I didn't know how to add a tooltip from R I tried a dirty way. I copied newer versions from [dimple](http://dimplejs.org) into my local dimple/js directory. Upgrading config.yml to v.2.0 gives what you expected and what makes me very happy. And even more it is running in firefox too.
But unfortunately with version v.2.1 it doesn't work again.

Comment: you could try devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/rCharts@dimple_v2.0.0") which is the branch that is under development to upgrade dimple.

Comment: thats a much better way and it works well. Thank you very much.